# On the justification behind a big O manipulation (quick question).

Tags: real-analysis

If $n \in N$ and $0<z \in R $, what is the rigorous justification behind the following big O manipulation?

\begin{align}
\left(1+\frac{(\log z)^2}{2n}+O\left(\frac1{n^{3/2}} \right)\right)^n
&=e^{(\log z)^2/2}+O\left(\frac1{n^{1/2}} \right) 
\end{align}

Comment: Stirling's approximation is likely useful here: $n^n \simeq n!/(\sqrt{n})$

Comment: It looks like a power series expansion for $e^x$ is showing up as well as the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity I set $y = (\log z)^2/2$, which is a real constant. Pass to logarithm:
$$
n \log \left (1+\frac{y}{n}+O\left ( \frac{1}{n^{3/2}} \right ) \right ) = n\left [\frac{y}{n} + O\left ( \frac{1}{n^{3/2}} \right ) \right ] = y + O\left ( \frac{1}{n^{1/2}} \right ).
$$

In the first equality I throwed away a term $O(1/n^2)$ within the parenthesis. Now exponentiate back!
$$
e^y \cdot e^{O(1/n^{1/2})} = e^y \cdot \left [1 + O\left ( \frac{1}{n^{1/2}} \right ) \right ] = e^y + O\left ( \frac{1}{n^{1/2}} \right ).
$$

In the first equality I throwed away a term $O(1/n)$ within the parenthesis.